# Add delay between ajax json calls

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

Sorry in advance if this isn't the proper way to ask this, please let me know how I can improve my questions :)

Essentially I have a json file which I want to pull data from (name, address, etc) in order to use a Google Maps API function to plot them as markers. This is the current ajax function I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'directory.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.group).each(function(index, person) {
        if (typeof person.Address != "undefined") {
            geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, person);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

However, this is calling the geocodeAddress function for all 800+ of my directory entries all at once, which is far above my Maps API query limit. I'd like to space these out ~100ms apart to prevent this. I tried using setInterval like to accomplish this, but it seems that the geocodeAddress line is run for all entries at once, so this would only delay all of the functions, not the length between each.

Is there another way I could pull this json data instead of using ajax, or just a way to delay each API request individually?

geocodeAddress function for reference (it both geocodes and plots markers)

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, person) {

  //geocoding address
  geocoder.geocode({'address': person.Address[0].text}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {

        //plotting coordinate as marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: resultsMap,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            icon: {
              url: person.Image[0].src,
              size: new google.maps.Size(120, 150),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 38),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 19)
            }
        });

      } else {
          console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: is data.group an Array?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, with the indexes representing each person. Other information is stored within them.

Comment: what is `geocodeAddress` function? can it be made to return a Promise?

Comment: @JaromandaX edited my original post to include the function

Comment: Did you want the delay to be between starting each geocode, or delay from one completing to the next starting?

Comment: @JaromandaX ideally the latter, such that geocodeAddress is called for group[0], 100ms passes, then geocodeAddress is called for group[1] (purely to space out API calls and prevent query limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the `geocodeAddress` calling with a 100ms spaced out time like below,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'directory.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(data) {
        var i = 0;
        var loop = function(){
            if(i < data.group.length){
                if (typeof data.group[i].Address != "undefined")
                   geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, data.group[i]);
                i++; 
                setTimeout(loop, 100);
            }
        }
        loop();
    }
});
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This seemed to work (although I'm sure the other solutions would as well). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add delays to your array iteration using `setTimeout` inside an IIFE:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'directory.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: 'false',
  success: function(data) {
    //Invoke delayLoop with initial params - i = 0, delay = 100ms
    (delayLoop)(0, data.group, 100, geocodePerson);
  }
});

//Function to perform delayed iteration function on array elements
function delayLoop (i, list, interval, itemFunc) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    itemFunc(list[i]);
    if (++i < list.length) {
      delayLoop(i, list, interval, itemFunc);
    }
  }, interval)
}

//function to perform on array elements
function geocodePerson(person) {
  if (typeof person.Address != "undefined") {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, person);
  }
}
```

Comment: where would i be coming from here? the ajax function doesn't seem to include any sort of variable representing an index (which would be ideal)

Comment: `data.group` is an array correct? using this approach you can initialize i to be 0 then iterate through the array

Comment: yep, but how would that look in the context of the ajax function? not sure where the function geocodeList fits into this

Comment: i've updated the answer to include the invocation of delayLoop in the success handler of the ajax call - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

With a little mod to your geocodeAddress function, to add an optional callback

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, person, callback) {
    //geocoding address
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': person.Address[0].text
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {

            //plotting coordinate as marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                icon: {
                    url: person.Image[0].src,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(120, 150),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 38),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 19)
                }
            });

        } else {
            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

and, for the sake of minimal changes, adding a wrapper function for geocodeAddress that returns a Promise

```
function geocodeAddressPromise(geocoder, resultsMap, person) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, person, resolve);
    };
}
```

Your main code can be written as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'directory.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: 'false'
}).then(function(data) {
    return data.group.filter(function(person) {
        return typeof person.Address != "undefined";
    }).reduce(function(promise, person) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            return geocodeAddressPromise(geocoder, map, person);
        }).then(function() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                setTimeout(resolve, 100);
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
});
```

it uses .filter to include only persons with an address

and a fairly common .reduce pattern to chain Promises in sequence, with the addition of the 100ms timeout between resolution of one address to the start of the next geocode call